# wordpress - post thumbnail is not showing up

Tags: wordpress, loops, thumbnails

Id like to show the list of post thumbnails from specified user, using this code:

```
global $user;
$numposts = get_posts( array('author' => $user->ID) );

<?php foreach ($numposts as $numpost) {
the_post_thumbnail();
} ?>
```

Thumbnails not showing up though. Am I doing something wrong? This code is inserted in plugin php file. thx

Answer (score 0):

Reworked and works:

```
$numposts = get_posts( array('author' => $user->ID) );

<?php
$my_query = new WP_Query( array( 'author' => $user->ID ) );
while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();

{

echo the_post_thumbnail();

}

endwhile;
?>
```

although not sure why it didnt work first time.